# I have to create the pivot table and pivot chart based on the sharepoint list data 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-services, content-editor-web-part

I need to create the pivot table and pivot chart based on the sharepoint list data 2010.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Share something that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint and SQL in integrated mode then you will get an option on the list ribbon to add the list as a data source to PowerPivot.

If not then see if this helps?  http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/07/11/excel-services-using-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source.aspx